# Dask Dataframe groupby and aggregate for column

Tags: pandas-groupby, grouping, dask, multiplication, dask-dataframe

I had a pd.DataFrame that I converted to Dask.DataFrame for faster computations.
My requirement is that I have to find out the 'Total Views' of a channel.

In pandas it would be, `df.groupby(['ChannelTitle'])['VideoViewCount'].sum()` but in dask the columns dtypes is `object` and `groupby` is taking these as string and not `int`(*see image 2*)

To handle above issue, I added two columns separating figure(115) and multiplier(6 for M, 3 for K) of views hoping to do an operation like `ddf['new_views_f'] * (10**ddf['new_views_m'])`, but now I cannot find `mul` for two columns in dask.

Either I am missing something or complicating the requirement.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you are complicating the requirement. For column multiplication, the regular pandas syntax will work (`df['c'] = df['a'] * df['b']`). In your case, it's possible to use `pd.eval` to get the actual numeric value for views:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(15*np.random.rand(15), columns=['views'])
df['views'] = df['views'].round(2).astype('str') + [random.choice(['K views', 'M views']) for _ in range(len(df))]
df['group'] = [random.choice([1,2,3]) for _ in range(len(df))]
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf['views_digits'] = ddf['views'].replace({'K views': '*1e3', 'M views': '*1e6'}, regex=True).map(pd.eval, meta=ddf['group'])
aggregate_df = ddf.groupby(['group']).agg({'views_digits': 'sum'}).compute()
```

Comment: But what I need is the operations you are performing on df (line 8 & 9) also on ddf.

Comment: Yes, they are performed on `ddf`, the pandas in the first few lines is only to provide a reproducible example. You can delete those lines and replace them with `ddf = dd.read_csv()` or code for another way that you create `ddf`.